# Simple Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the two following differential equations:

(1) $ f''(t) = 3f'(t) - f(t)$

(2) $ f''(t) = 2f'(t) - f(t)$

I chose the approach $f(t) = e^{\lambda t}$ and hence arrive for the first case at

$\lambda^2 e^{\lambda t} = e^{\lambda t}(3\lambda - 1) \rightarrow \lambda^2 = 3 \lambda - 1$

and for the second differential equation I arrive at $\lambda^2 = 2 \lambda - 1$

Is this correct? How do I find $\lambda$ now per hand easily?
Also, in the exercise it says "find the solution and determine what $\lambda$ is" - but isn't that the same thing?

Also: For the second case, is $t*e^{\lambda t}$ also a solution?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, my fault, corrected.

Comment: You can write these as quadratics to solve $m^2-3m+1 = 0$ and $m^2-2m+1$. Clear?

Comment: Well, the second one is obviously pretty simple to solve (m = 1), but what approach do I need to solve the first one manually? Also, is that then the solution to the diffeq already when plugged in? And what about t*e^lambda*t as a solution for the 2nd one? As far as I see it works too, right?

Comment: It is just the roots of the [*quadratic formula*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Quadratic_formula_and_its_derivation). For the second we have a double root of $1$, which makes the solution $y = e^t + t e^t$.

Comment: How to I arrive systematically to a solution like this, from knowing about the double root?

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/RepeatedRoots.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to find $\lambda$ easily such as the quadratic formula or doing some algebra. In this case, let's do the last one , so, for example: 
$$
\lambda^2 -2\lambda + 1 =0 \\
(\lambda - 1)^2 = 0 \\
\lambda = 1
$$

But $\lambda$ is not the solution of the differential equation. Instead:

$$
f(x) = C_1 e^{\lambda_1x} + C_2 e^{\lambda_2x} + \dots + C_n e^{\lambda_nx}
$$

Where $C_i$ are constants. That's true if $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2 \neq \dots \neq \lambda_n$. In our case, $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$, so both solutions would be linearly dependent. To fix that, the solution should be:

$$
f(x) = C_1 e^{\lambda_1x} + x\,C_2 e^{\lambda_1x} + \dots + x^n \,C_n e^{\lambda_1x}
$$

Where $n$ is the multiplicity of $\lambda$

Answer (score 0):

Just solve the quadratic equation for $\lambda$. ;-)